# Module compiled with Swift 5.2.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3 compiler with xcode 12.1

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, compiler-errors

My project was running perfect with xcode 11.4.1 but when i tried to run project xcode 12.1. I got error "**Module compiled with Swift 5.2.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3 compiler with xcode 12.1**".
Please see attached image. **Thanks!**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/39k04.png

Comment: BuckoNetworking This library not supported in your Xcode version so please update or change. Xcode 12.1 only support after Swift 4.0.

Comment: I have fixed this issue via remove Carthage from project and added all those modules which was in Carthage via pod and manual add BuckoNetworking files in the project because BuckoNetworking was not available in pod. Import all module in BuckoNetworking files which needed to that files to run project.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced same error in Razorpay integreation in a project. I have down grade my xcode version to the supported swift version and the error gone.

Please suggest any other option, if you found. Some thing which does not require to down grade xcode version and works.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue via remove Carthage from project and added all those modules which was in Carthage via pod and manual add BuckoNetworking files in the project because BuckoNetworking was not available in pod. Import all module in BuckoNetworking files which needed to that files to run project.